# Cat a file Multiple times Without A Loop

Tags: bash, shell, unix

This is NOT a homework question, this is a question from an old exam, so anyone giving an answer will not be contributing to academic dishonesty. For those still skeptical, I am simply seeking what command I could use for this.

You have a file called one_mb which is exactly 1 megabyte in size. You want to create from it a file of exactly 128 megabytes in size. Please write a shell script to do this with at most 9 lines and no loops, if statements, recursion, or any other logic control structures. Each command, including parameters, must be less than 100 characters in length.

I began to research xarg, but could not figure out a good way to use it to accomplish this.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Assuming bash, you can use a one-line brace expansion hack:

```
cat one_mb{,}{,}{,}{,}{,}{,}{,} > 128_mb
```

Comment: I think it's probably safe to assume bash since the question has a `bash` tag. But, if I were marking this, I may well take off marks for being a smart-a** :-) No, not really, good hack.

Answer (score 12):

Not sure if this counts, but this came to mind:

```
seq 1 128 | xargs -Inone cat one_mb >> 128_mb
```

No loops were used, just a pipe and `xargs`.

Comment: Thanks for using xargs, still do not see how it works, but that is a pretty sweet oneliner

Comment: This simplified command might help you understand what is going on a bit better: `seq 1 10 | xargs -I{} echo Doing {}` Also, check out the xargs man pages!

Comment: Thank-you for the simplified version.
I did not intend to ask for clarification, I abide by the law of RTFM, so I did read the man page, but having examples helps to make to clarify for better than a high level description of the functionality.

Answer (score 4):

The big hint here is that it can be "no more than 9 lines". Since 2^7 = 128, you just need to double the file's size 7 times:

```
cat one_mb one_mb > two_mb
cat two_mb two_mb > four_mb
...
cat 64_mb 64_mb > 128_mb
```

Comment: I'm curious why they were given 9 commands, then, instead of 7. Room for error, I guess :)

Comment: maybe it is: line 1: shebang, lines 2-8: the code above, line 9: cleanup.. (removing the temporary files)

Comment: This was the prevailing method.

Answer (score 4):

At 100 characters per command, you could reduce it quite a bit:

```
cat one_mb one_mb one_mb one_mb one_mb one_mb one_mb one_mb >mb8
cat mb8 mb8 mb8 mb8 >mb32
cat mb32 mb32 mb32 mb32 >mb128
rm -f mb8 mb32
```

Answer (score 2):

```
dd oflag=append conv=notrunc if=/dev/zero of=one_mb bs=1MB count=127
```

This will retain the file content and add a bunch of "zero" records to make it 128 MB. Do

```
ls -ltrh one_mb
```

to check if it actually is 128MB, otherwise you might have to change the "count=127" parameter.

Answer (score -1):

I think it would be enough with the constraints you have. You can define a function that takes an integer as parameter. If it's greater than 0, `cat`s the file and calls the same function again, but with the parameter decreased.

Then you just call the function with the value needed, and you're done.

Good ol' recursion :)

(Sorry, too lazy for coding, and there are lots of other working answers, just wanted to avoid recursion being forgotten :))

Comment: "Please write a shell script to do this with at most 9 lines and **no** loops, if statements, **recursion**, or any other logic control structures."

Comment: It was __really__ too late, I thought "if statements, recursion, etc" were allowed. My bad.